# css left right simple menu

Tags: html, css

I want to have something like this:

```
================================
====IMAGE==============TEXT=====
================================
```

and I used:

```
.menu {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: right;
}
.menu img {
    float: left;
}
```

Result:

```
================================
=======================TEXT=====
====IMAGE=======================
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Give menu a specific width..

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2WxKK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to use line-height with height in your text and set a width to your menu, something like:

```
<div class="menu">
   <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50" />
   </div>
   <div class="text">
      <p>your text</p>
   </div>
</div>

.menu {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: right;
    width:100%;
}
.menu img {
    float: left;
}

.menu text {
    float: left;
}

.text p{
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hAAk7/)

Answer (score 1):

You would need the image to be first in the markup. Float will make inline items wrap around something, but only the inline items that come *after* it in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Elements are not getting exact float and width property.

```
.menu {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px;
  float: right;
  max-width: 40%;
}
.menu img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 60%;
}
```

Now try to wrap them and use

```
.wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
}
```